# Xero API - Insert unique QR code onto Xero Payslips via API

Tags: api, xero-api

Can someone from Xero help me with a request, as there are no email addresses on the developer page.

I was wanting to insert a unique QR code with information gathered from an API Post response onto payslips and perhaps invoices.

Is there an API endpoint to do this?

Thanks

Robert

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this is not supported, I will see what I can find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to inject QR codes onto invoices or payslips, you could post this idea to the Payroll API team at Xero here -> https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/250567-xero-payroll-api

Comment: Thanks Steven, thats helpful